# Issue authenticating Web App and Web Api in Azure

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I deployed a Web APP and Web API project to Azure App Service. Added authentication to my Web App and Web Api using Azure Active Directory. But now when I am calling Web Api from my Web App I am getting below error. I have already enabled CORS in my web api.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.windows.net/2xxxxxxx/oauth2/autho…Fvalues%2FGetMaxDate&nonce=80daeef12xxxxxxxxxx_201xxxxxxx453. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If I remove Azure Active Directory Authentication from my web api everything works fine. But I cannot remove authentication from my web api as entering api url from browser will give user json data.

Comment: I just want to clarify you scenario. You have deployed Web APP and Web API to different domains, right? Web APP should access Web API?

Comment: @AlexanderAndronov Yes. https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net/ this is the URL of the Web app. It is trying to access https://mywebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/GetMenu

Comment: The right way to protect Web API is to use Bearer Tokens. CORS is useful if you are trying to access you webapi via ajax calls. Take a look: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet/

Comment: @AlexanderAndronov I am trying to acesss web api via ajax call from my web app. So you are telling me to remove authentication from web api and instead use jwt bearer token? In that case api controller without [Authorized] tag will be directly accessible even for unauthenticated user.

Comment: Well, for me it looks strange..you would better access your Web APP from javascript and then send request to Web API to get actual data. It will simplify communications between different parts of you app